# What happens if stack memory becomes full

Tags: .net

May be my question is irrelevant, it will probably may never happened as stack has 1MB of memory.

But if stack memory becomes full, what will happen. Because garbage collector will not perform cleaning for stack.

Comment: Please check the name of this website. That's what happens when the stack becomes full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy to overflow the stack:

```
int* ptr = stackalloc int[4000000];
```

A StackOverflowException will occur.

Answer (score 2):

When the stack fills up, you get a `StackOverflowException` exception.

Of course the stack may fill up, if your code has a bug which causes runaway recursion, or if you use recursion to implement an algorithm which is unsuitable for recursion, like for example linear search.

You can very easily check what happens with runaway recursion like this:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    Main( args );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely not an expert, but my guess would be a `StackOverflowException`.

I don't think you'll ever fill the whole 1MB stack though.

Comment: It's very easy if you've got a method that (directly or indirectly) calls itself and isn't actually making any forward progress.